# Can't Create a Powershell Alias

Tags: powershell, alias, scoping

I can’t get PowerShell aliases to work. My code (called at the beginning of my script):

```
function Set-Aliases {
   Set-Alias -name csttc -value Convert-ServerTypeToTitleCase
}
```

Later, I call it like this:

```
Confirm-ChangeSuccess -item "$(csttc -server $server) user" -newValue $newValue
```

It returns this error message:

```
The term 'csttc' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm running Visual Studio Code 1.81.0. My $PSVersionTable

```
PSVersion                      7.3.6
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.6
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Comment: Make sure you dot-source `Set-Aliases`, eg. `. Set-Aliases`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerShell, **aliases, like functions and variables, are *scoped***, and **by default** they are **created in the *current* [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes)**, which means that ***only that scope and its descendants* see it**.

Since functions execute in a *child* scope when invoked directly (or via `&`), your alias definition was only visible inside your `Set-Aliases` definition and went out of scope when the function returned.

Therefore:

- To define your aliases in the *caller*'s scope (whatever it may be), [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) your function:

  ```bash
  # Dot-sourcing (`. `) runs the function directly in the caller's scope.
  . Set-Aliases
  ```

  - Note that PowerShell's [`$PROFILE` files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) are *implicitly* dot-sourced, so if you place [`Set-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias) calls *directly* in such a file, they will become globally available in the session.
- To define your aliases *globally* (whatever scope you're calling from), define your function as follows - regular invocation will then do:

  ```bash
  # Note the use of `-Scope Global`
  function Set-Aliases {
    Set-Alias -Scope Global -Name csttc -Value Convert-ServerTypeToTitleCase
  }

  # Normal invocation now defines the alias *globally*
  Set-Aliases
  ```

Comment: You’re right. Using -scope did the trick. Glad it was something simple!

Comment: @mklement0 - mind blown… I didn’t realise you could dot-source *commands* - as far as I can see, the documentation only really mentions *scripts*. Once again after using this site I’m left wondering what *else* I still don’t know about PowerShell :-).

Comment: I always thought of dot sourcing as ```. <filename>``` but in retrospect, the error message for, e.g. ```. zzz``` says “The term 'zzz' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.”, which makes it pretty clear it’s more like ```. <command>```, with  the ```<filename>``` above simply being a command name. I learned something today at least :-).

Comment: @mclayton :) script blocks too can be dot-sourced (though I suspect you knew that part). Another possibly surprising aspect: a dot-sourced function doesn't necessarily run in the _caller_'s scope. If the function originates from a _module_, in runs in _that module_'s current scope.